# lsituil basic usage : identify broken disk

Tags: centos, raid, hard-drive, hardware-raid, lsi

We have one disk broken on a server (according to nagios).

I would like to get information about the broken disk.

I tried to type lsiutil -s.

Unfortunately the output doesn't show which physical disk is broken.

LSI Logic MPT Configuration Utility, Version 1.62, January 14, 2009
Centos 6.3

Do you know where I can get a kind a cheat sheet about lsituil?

What would be the command line to identify the broken disk?

The documentation is obfuscated (http://www.thomas-krenn.com/de/wikiDE/images/4/44/Lsi_userguide_2006_20130528.pdf).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what software for raid / volume management do you use?
I know about that documentation, unfortunately I have never seen a non-complicated documentation of lsiutil. My best guess would be to reach out to avago (they aquired LSI recently) for any documentation.

Comment: @JonasStig: First, welcome to [sf]. Please read our [help] to learn about the site and how to answer questions. That said, it's really unlikely that LSI has some other, better secret docs lying around they only give to customers contacting them directly and ask nicely...